# Question regarding Application of Combinations and Permutations (HW Problem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a midterm I am studying for and I don't have the solutions to this homework problem. Can anyone please explain how to do it? I would really appreciate it.
Here is the problem:

[image: two tables of MATHEMATICS letters]

I googled the answer for this question, but I did not understand the solution. Can anyone please explain or give their own interpretation of the answer? Thanks!!

http://users.wpi.edu/~hservat/cs2022d12finalsolutions.pdf

Page 2 has the solution I am confused about.

Comment: Please review [ask].  Your Readers will benefit from making the body of the Question as self-contained as possible.  Here the burden of posing a problem has been delegated to following one or more links.  Better to explain the solution you found in your own words as this will tend to disclose what is giving you difficulty.

Comment: It would improve your Question to include your own efforts at a solution.  As you have asked about two tables, some thoughts about which one has an easier solution (and why) should be articulable.

Answer (score 1):

To traverse the grid, you must move 5 steps right and 5 steps down in some order.   So you want to count the distinct permutations of the string: $\rm RRRRRDDDDD$

There are $10!$ ways to arrange $10$ symbols, but all $5$ $\rm R$ symbols, and all $5$ $\rm D$ symbols are each interchangeable.   So there are $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$ ways to arrange the string.

*Alternatively:* We count the ways to select $5$ of the $10$ places for the $\rm R$ symbols, then place the $\rm D$ symbols in the unselected places.   That is $\binom{10}{5}$ ways, which is equal to $\frac{10!}{5!5!}$.

---

In general, the count of such paths in an $(m+1)\times (n+1)$ node grid is $\binom{m+n}{n}$ or $\binom{m+n}{m}$ (they're equal).

---

For the second table, break the grid into whole rectangle sections.   Count the ways to reach the two $\rm E$, then from each to the one or two $\rm T$ and then the $\rm S$

$$\binom{5}{1}1\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{3}\left(1\binom{3}{2}+\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\right)$$